# Angular-material autocomplete items one digest cycle behind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

[Example](http://codepen.io/jpumford/pen/GqWdQY?editors=1111)

Open the console and watch as the `$ctrl.items` updates based on your typing. However, it seems as if the displayed autocomplete is always one digest cycle behind what is being typed.

[image: abc]

[image: abcd]